# Build table with previous months (cumulative)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm a bit lost with the following problem that I need to solve with an SQL query, no plsql. The idea is to build a cumulative column to calculate all previous months. The input table looks like

```
 Month
 1
 2
 3
 ..
 24
```

I need build the following table :

```
Month Cum_Month
1     1
2     1
2     2
3     1
3     2
3     3
..
24    1
...
24    23
```

All this in SQL Server 2008, thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE ([Month] INT)
INSERT @tbl VALUES
(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),
(11),(12),(13),(14),(15),(16),(17),(18),(19),(20),(21),(22),(23),(24)


SELECT  Month
        ,   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Month ORDER BY Month) num
FROM    @tbl a
JOIN    
(
    SELECT  *
    FROM    master..spt_values 
    WHERE   type = 'P'
)
b ON b.number < a.Month
```

`master..spt_values` is used to generate numbers, after numbers are generated result of the subquery is joined on the `@tbl` to get the number of rows that corresponds to the `month`. After that `ROW_NUMBER` is used to create appropriate ordinal numbers for each month.

Comment: @icCube Great, I'm glad to help :) If you find this answer most useful you can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pretty cool trick not using any tables:

```
SELECT N.Number as Month, N2.Number as Cum_Month
FROM 
   (SELECT Number FROM master..spt_values WHERE Number BETWEEN 1 AND 24 AND Type = 'P') N
   JOIN (SELECT Number FROM master..spt_values WHERE Number BETWEEN 1 AND 24 AND Type = 'P') N2 ON N.Number >= N2.Number
ORDER BY N.Number, N2.Number
```

And the [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/da78c/6).

And if you really don't want the last 24 24 (why not), just change the second query to between 1 and 23).

Comment: That's also cool but I can only give one correct answer even though I got to different but correct ones. Thanks